# NSURLSession method returning true or false on login

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I have this UIViewController, that calls a web service.

In order to make any call to that web service, I need to first login.
After a successful login, I receive

- a session cookie
- user-specific data

I need this data for any subsequent calls to the server.

So, a simple approach would be (pseudo code):

```
if([self Login]){
    [self getSomeJsonDataForThisUser];
}
```

Now, the problem is, that, being a good citizen, I'm moving away from NSURLConnection, and that NSURLSessions are all async.

The basic question is:
how can I write a method like this:

```
-(BOOL)Login{
  --do some async stuff here
  --return TRUE or FALSE
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Iff I am able to get your question then you are asking how to call the WS from NSURLSession. If yes, then simple create NSURLSession & NSURLSessionDataTask as below   NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URLStringHere"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
    }];

Comment: Looked into that, but i cannot use that in a method that needs to return a BOOL.

Comment: why not, you can return a bool based on your response coming from server as -(BOOL)Login{
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession]; NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URLStringHere"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) { if (error){return NO;}else{return YES;} }]
)

Comment: @Gagan_iOS No, you definitely can **not** return something from an asynchronous task via the return value of a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the asynchronous behavior you need a method with a completion handler

```
- (void)loginWithCompletion: (void (^)(BOOL))completion {
    // do some async stuff here
    completion(true); // This line returns the result of the task.
}
```

and use it

```
[self loginWithCompletion:^(BOOL result) {
    NSLog(@"result: %d", result);
    if (result) {
        [self getSomeJsonDataForThisUser];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Hang on. Let me try that. Get back to you.

Comment: Thanks. This is it.

Comment: I would like to give you more than the usual credits: this opened my eyes wide to both the phenomenon of async operations as well as the completion handlers. I'm much wiser now. THANKS. THANKS.